# Error 500 when accessing Gitlab browser interface

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-omnibus

I'm running an instance of Gitlab Omnibus CE, version 8.15.2, on CentOS 7.3.1611. Upgrading from the 8.14 release family didn't go quite according to plan; since doing that, I've been unable to access the Gitlab browser interface.

When I try to access the browser interface, I can access the login screen and log in, but after I'm logged in, going to any page results in an Error 500: Whoops, something went wrong on our end.

So I used gitlab-ctl tail to grab some log data for what's happening, and it looks like it's a problem with Postgresql's data for one of my projects:

http://pastebin.com/VDMk0eKr

But I'm not sure how I should fix this. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It's [known issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/26060) that's been [fixed](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/commit/090ede2d60b18da8946a9929def77c4afd990d96) with newest release 8.15.3. If you don't want to upgrade GitLab, there is an existing [workaround](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/26060) (**Edit:** as mentioned in comment, the workaround does not always work so consider upgrade primary)

> File:
>   `/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/app/models/concerns/has_status.rb`
>
> Replace
>
> ```
> builds = scope.select('count(*)').to_sql
> created = scope.created.select('count(*)').to_sql
> success = scope.success.select('count(*)').to_sql
> pending = scope.pending.select('count(*)').to_sql
> running = scope.running.select('count(*)').to_sql
> skipped = scope.skipped.select('count(*)').to_sql
> canceled = scope.canceled.select('count(*)').to_sql
> ```
>
> with
>
> ```
> builds = scope.select('count(*)').reorder(nil).to_sql
> created = scope.created.select('count(*)').reorder(nil).to_sql
> success = scope.success.select('count(*)').reorder(nil).to_sql
> pending = scope.pending.select('count(*)').reorder(nil).to_sql
> running = scope.running.select('count(*)').reorder(nil).to_sql
> skipped = scope.skipped.select('count(*)').reorder(nil).to_sql
> canceled = scope.canceled.select('count(*)').reorder(nil).to_sql
> ```
>
> And restart GitLab.

Comment: I am using GitLab Version 8.15.1 but the above solutions not worked for me https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/26060 Please suggest the upgrade process.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and the above didn't work so I ran the following command to downgrade.

To check the current version istalled:

```
sudo dpkg -l | grep gitlab-ce
```

To see which versions were available:

```
sudo apt-cache madison gitlab-ce | less
```

and the following to "downgrade", since I was at 9.2.0-rc2.ce.0 shown by the above command:

```
sudo apt-get install gitlab-ce=9.2.0-rc1.ce.0
```

Comment: In newer versions, using the raspberrypi, I have seen large memory commitments that have been causing the same style of error as noted above. I have used "htop" to see the memory commitment. I was able to make gitlab stable by using the process below to move swap into ram with zram. https://www.novaspirit.com/2016/12/24/increasing-ram-raspberry-pi/